# Page content height dependent on jumbotron container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, absolute

I am using a jumbotron with the following css:

```
.jumbotron-billboard .img {
    opacity: 0.95;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000 url("http://localhost/wp-content/themes/img/jumbotron.jpg") center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    top:0;left:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
.jumbotron {background:white;}

.jumbotron .container {
  position:relative;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  border-radius:10px;
  top:20px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Due to absolute position of the image, it is out of the flow and the whole content below is dependent on the jumbotron container size. This either leads to an unpresentable merge of the background image with the below content or too much spacing depending on different window size.

Is there a way to make the background image more...dynamic?

Here is an image where the content interfers with the background image: [http://imgur.com/a/IRVMA](https://imgur.com/a/IRVMA)

Comment: Could you post some images of how it looks right now. I can't visualize your problem.

Comment: @MarkoMackic I added an image to see exactly where it interferes. This would not happen if the background-image was not absolutely positioned.